# LPC-Link2 Not Working as CMSIS-DAP with OpenOCD

Tags: lpc, nxp, openocd

I'm working on a project with the NXP LPC824 using VisualGDB and OpenOCD. Using the LPCXpresso824-MAX dev board I had no trouble programming and debugging using OpenOCD. I am using the version of OpenOCD that comes with VisualGDB (0.10.0). I have recently built my first prototype PCB for this project and purchased an LPC-Link2 to use as a CMSIS-DAP debugger with it. However, I am unable to get the LPC-Link2 to work with OpenOCD. I keep getting a "CMSIS-DAP command CMD_INFO failed" error.

I have flashed the CMSIS-DAP firmware to the LPC-Link2, reinstalled the drivers, and followed any other troubleshooting tips I could find, but with no success. The LPC-Link2 works when flashed with the Segger J-Link firmware and also with the CMSIS-DAP firmware when debugging through MCUXpresso, so it does not appear to be a problem with the probe or the firmware but rather something specific to OpenOCD. There is nothing wrong with the target board because, as a workaround, I have removed the target MCU from the LPCXpresso824-MAX and am using its external debug header to debug the target MCU on my PCB.

Here is the output of my version of OpenOCD with the LPC-Link2 with debug turned on.

```
openocd.exe -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -c "debug_level 4"
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0 (2019-08-28) [https://github.com/sysprogs/openocd]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
User : 14 6 options.c:60 configuration_output_handler(): debug_level: 4
User : 15 9 options.c:60 configuration_output_handler():
Info : 16 13 server.c:311 add_service(): Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : 17 16 server.c:311 add_service(): Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Debug: 18 19 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - init init
Debug: 20 21 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - target target init
Debug: 22 23 command.c:143 script_debug(): command - target target names
Debug: 23 26 target.c:1431 handle_target_init_command(): Initializing targets...
Debug: 24 59 cmsis_dap_usb.c:251 cmsis_dap_usb_open(): Cannot read product string of device 0x46d:0xc232
Debug: 25 65 cmsis_dap_usb.c:251 cmsis_dap_usb_open(): Cannot read product string of device 0x46d:0xc231
Debug: 26 1075 cmsis_dap_usb.c:409 cmsis_dap_usb_xfer(): error reading data: (null)
Error: 27 1081 cmsis_dap_usb.c:503 cmsis_dap_cmd_DAP_Info(): CMSIS-DAP command CMD_INFO failed.
Debug: 28 1088 command.c:630 run_command(): Command 'init' failed with error code -107
User : 29 1103 command.c:695 command_run_line():
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is going wrong? Is this a bug with OpenOCD? I have a workaround in place now so this is not holding up development, but it would be nice to get it working.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out. 
I have the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Having a viable workaround has meant that I got sidetracked working on the actual project. I've just posted something similar on the OpenOCD SourceForge site to hopefully get a response from someone. [https://sourceforge.net/p/openocd/tickets/255/](https://sourceforge.net/p/openocd/tickets/255/)

Comment: I've ordered an external CMSIS programmer and a JLink programmer, I'll see if the CMSIS-DAP programmer has the same message as the LPC Link 2